# Nginx 443 taking too long to respond

Tags: nginx, https

I have checked that ufw is disabled. `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P` shows this:

```
COMMAND     PID          USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd       1059          root    3u  IPv4    15446      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1059          root    4u  IPv6    15448      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
mysqld     1181         mysql   20u  IPv4    16775      0t0  TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)
redis-ser  1242         redis    4u  IPv4    16537      0t0  TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN)
node\x20/  9098 administrator   13u  IPv6 29891806      0t0  TCP *:5555 (LISTEN)
nginx     15566          root    6u  IPv4 29921927      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     15566          root    7u  IPv4 29921928      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     15570      www-data    6u  IPv4 29921927      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     15570      www-data    7u  IPv4 29921928      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
node\x20/ 21806 administrator   12u  IPv6 29795008      0t0  TCP *:1341 (LISTEN)
```

https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ says that 443 is closed.

My nginx config(On removing ssl config it works fine on port 80 but not on 443):

```
server {
 listen 443 default_server ssl;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        server_name admin.....app.ch;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555/;

        }
       index index.html index.htm;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/../fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/../privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
```

Output of iptables -L -n:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:443

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Verbose:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 708K packets, 375M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 677K packets, 280M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: What does "taking too long to respond" mean? Is it responding at all on port 443? Does it work on port 80 if SSL is enabled? Do you have an external firewall that might block the connection?

Comment: Its a request timeout error. There is no external firewall

Comment: `ufw` is noting other than a wrapper around iptables. Check actual firewall rules using `iptables -L -n` and post output here.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Updated answer.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin You (and the OP) forgot `-v`. Without it, the complete firewall rules do not appear.

Comment: Added verbose output and nothing much appears.